# Network issue when using wget script

Tags: linux, networking, script

I asked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60315/wget-images-issue-from-api-key/60429#60429) question on the Unix & Linux site a few days back but I'm stuck with an answer of why.
We receive an `.xml` feed of new items from our apparel vendors but I cannot get the wget script I created to work in Linux.
I have tested the script on other sites and it works. However, if I use a windows based program, like **jdownloader**, I can retrieve the images.
Why would I be able to access a site with my secure credentials in Windows but not in Linux?  How can I correct this?  No one on our end or the vendors end can give me an answer.

UPDATED
**Example of the link given**:

```
> https://vendor/manufacter/4518799325.jpg?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

*Note it works in Windows and not in Linux*

Comment: Just like on the U&L site, we need to see the script and the urls in the file in order to suggest solutions.  Convert p/word etc info to <XXX> or similar.  Otherwise you'll be lucky if anyone on this end can give you an answer, either.

Comment: You answered your own question there and accepted it, is that incorrect?

Comment: the issue was not the script so I closed the thread.

Comment: Example of the code added.